# Jenkins - Jenkins Pipeline Step Plugin for AWS - how to update a service

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins I can build, tag and push docker images to the AWS ECR. This is possible after docker-login in via the Jenkins AWS plugin step 'withAWS()'.

To redeploy the latest image I can normally perform this shell command:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster spring-boot-cluster-6 --service spring-boot-service-6 --force-new-deployment
```

How can I execute this action via the Jenkins Pipeline Step Plugin for AWS?

This plugin is also known as 'jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSGettingStartedContinuousDeliveryPipeline/latest/GettingStarted/CICD_Jenkins_Pipeline.html)

In my case I have put the bash script within the source code, so the Jenkins pipeline simply executes it to create the new task definition and update the service.

Added from comments

Here you have some examples. github.com/jenkinsci/aws-credentials-plugin/issues/22 using withCredentials and the Jenkins secrets manager. Another option is to put them on a file in the host machine. In my case the route is /var/lib/jenkins/.aws/credentials . Another option is to use environment vars docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/…. This is the worst option as the secrets becomes visible in the pipeline code. – Carlos 2 hours ago   delete

Comment: I know this option, see my question above. Using that approach, I need to install both the Jenkins AWS Step plugin (for credentials) and the AWSCLI. So, I do hope the nice AWS step Plugin can update the service.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realized the last sentence. I'm not using that plugin, just some shell calls on the pipeline.

Comment: Here you have some examples. https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-credentials-plugin/issues/22 using withCredentials and the Jenkins secrets manager. Another option is to put them on a file in the host machine. In my case the route is /var/lib/jenkins/.aws/credentials . Another option is to use environment vars https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html. This is the worst option as the secrets becomes visible in the pipeline code.

Comment: Can you add this comment (with the 2 options) to you answer? Then I will mark it as 'solved'. Thank you!